# English - India's Currency and number format is not available

Tags: localization, windows-xp, windows-update

I am using Windows XP Service pack 2 (2002), I need Indian (Locale) Number and Currrency formats , but  the "English - India"  is not available in languages bar , I customized the Dollar symbol and digits grouping  in the "English - United States" but it does'nt work in the application I am using, what all I need is a update to make Available "English - India" in the language Options of Control Panel -->Region and Languages.

Answer (score 1):

The Indian Rupee Symbol was added as part of the [Unicode 6.0.0](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/) standard in early 2011.

[An update to support the new currency symbol for the Indian Rupee in Windows Vista, in Windows Server 2008, in Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2496898) was subsequently released by MS with updated fonts and the English (India) keyboard among other things (further details [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_sustained_engineering/archive/2011/03/22/support-for-the-new-indian-rupee-symbol.aspx)), but support for XP [was omitted](http://www.pcworld.com/article/223223/article.html).

The reason for this is XP entered its [extended support phase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP#Support_lifecycle) on April 14, 2009 (ending on April 8, 2014), and during this phase a product receives only security updates/patches.

At most you can copy over the fonts from an updated Vista+ PC and manually insert the Rupee symbol into your documents (you'll need to embed the font as well if the document will be read on XP). There will be no official updates to do what you want, so don't hold your breath.